# В sublime text 3 есть компилятор?

Tags: sublime-text-3, c99

Можно ли запустить код через приложение sublime text 3 или в нем не предусмотрено такого свойства ?

Answer (score 1):

Sublime text - это редактор, компилятор необходимо устанавливать отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть разные пакеты **Package Control** позволяющие это делать.
Сначала надо поставить сам **Package Control**
https://packagecontrol.io/installation
А затем поставить необходимые пакеты через
**Preferences->Package Control**
и там выбрать
**Install Package**.
В строке поиска можно искать пакеты по нужному языку или названию.
Есть разные пакеты, часть просто поддерживает подсветку синтаксиса, а часто может запускать код и выводить результаты выполнения.
Коенкретно по С не подскажу, но для Golang собираю прямо в Sublime, для Си вариантов пакетов на порядок больше чем для Golang, можно найти то что понравится.